# R script works on one data file, but not on another one of the same type

Tags: r, dplyr, dataset, data-cleaning

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yjvesdycs6n91ee/pecfas_100233%20%5Bmi-%20washtenaw%20community%20health%20orgnization%5D.csv?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/v41dpf64rhysqum/pecfas_100203%20%5Bmi-%20southwest%20counseling%20solutions%5D.csv?dl=0

Above are links to two data files. Below is my R script. Briefly, the R script opens these files, deletes several unnecessary variables, creates other variables, and generally makes the dataset closer to something that I can work with. My problem is that while it is working on the Washtenaw file and 14 other similar files, it is NOT working with the Southwest Counseling file.

The problem arises towards the end of the code with the variables rec.cols, rec.colnames, and fas. 
**When I try to use rec.colnames as names, I get the error that the names attribute contains more items than the vector.** 
I understand the concept of this issue: rec.colnames has roughly 70 items, and rec.cols is supposedly 0 columns and 1 row. However, this should not be the case. I do not have this problem with any other file. I would like someone to help me figure out why this is happening, and also what I can do to fix it.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

# even after the item-level data is deleted from each data set, when all of the data sets are merged, the merged file is still too large to manipulate efficiently
# however, only the data from the initial and last assessments within the year of interest are needed for the reports
# the function below only deletes assessment data that are not from the initial or last assessments

del.mid <- function(file){

  lower <- str_match(pattern = "cafas|pecfas", string = file)
  upper <- toupper(lower) 

  fas <- fread(input = paste0("data/", lower, "/items-del/", file), sep = ",", header = TRUE, na.strings = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, colClasses = "character", fill = TRUE, data.table = FALSE)

  #
  # some cases have assessments entered that do not have any scores
  # remove all data for these assessments so that they are not used as the initial most recent assessment
  #

  fas.long <- fas %>%
    gather(key = key, value = value, starts_with(paste0(upper, "_E")), na.rm = FALSE) %>%
    separate(col = key, into = c("scale", "time", "var"), sep = "_", extra = "merge") %>%
    spread(key = var, value = value)

  other.vars <- c("episodeNum", "clientAge", "assessID", "VersionNum", "SA_SoftwareID", "SA_ID", "Prog_SoftwareID", "Prog_ID", "assessDate", "daysSinceEpisodeStart", "status", "isLocked", "isDeleted", "isAmendment", "adminDesc", "adminMonths", "adminOtherDesc", "timePeriod", "noSubsequent", "language", "youthLivArrange", "youthLivArrangeIsOther", "youthOtherLivArrange", "assessorSoftwareID", "Primary_CaregiverID", "Primary_CaregiverRelation")

  # score variables for the CAFAS and PECFAS are different

  if(lower == "cafas") score.vars <- c("TotalScore", "TotalStrengths", "Tier", "ChildMgmtSkills", "PervasBhImpair", "RiskPsychotic", "RiskSevereSubstance", "RiskSuicideAttempt", "RiskSuicideIdeation", "RiskAggresive", "RiskSexual", "RiskFire", "RiskRunaway", "RiskExceedPrimaryCG", "RiskExceedNonCust", "RiskExceedSurrogate", "TotalSevere", "TotalScoreDiff", "MeaningfulReliableDiff", "SevereDiff", "PervasiveImpairDiff", "IndicatorImprove", "SchoolScore", "SchoolStrengthTotal", "HomeScore", "HomeStrengthTotal", "CommunityScore", "CommunityStrengthTotal", "BehaviorScore", "BehaviorStrengthTotal", "MoodScore", "MoodStrengthTotal", "SelfHarmScore", "SelfHarmStrengthTotal", "SubstanceScore", "SubstanceStrengthTotal", "ThinkingScore", "ThinkingStrengthTotal", "CG_P_Needs", "CG_P_Support", "Primary_CG_StrengthTotal", "NonCust_CaregiverID", "NonCust_CaregiverRelation", "NC_CG_Needs", "NC_CG_Support", "NC_CG_StrengthTotal", "Surr_CaregiverID", "Surr_CaregiverRelation", "Surr_CG_Needs", "Surr_CG_Support", "Surr_CG_StrengthTotal")

  if(lower == "pecfas") score.vars <- c("TotalScore", "TotalStrengths", "Tier", "ChildMgmtSkills", "PervasBhImpair", "RiskThinking", "RiskSuicideAttempt", "RiskSuicideIdeation", "RiskAggresive", "RiskSexual", "RiskFire", "RiskRunaway", "RiskDelinquent", "RiskExceedPrimaryCG", "RiskExceedNonCust", "RiskExceedSurrogate", "TotalSevere", "TotalScoreDiff", "MeaningfulReliableDiff", "SevereDiff", "PervasiveImpairDiff", "IndicatorImprove", "SchoolScore", "SchoolStrengthTotal", "HomeScore", "HomeStrengthTotal", "CommunityScore", "CommunityStrengthTotal", "BehaviorScore", "BehaviorStrengthTotal", "MoodScore", "MoodStrengthTotal", "SelfHarmScore", "SelfHarmStrengthTotal", "ThinkingScore", "ThinkingStrengthTotal", "CG_P_Needs", "CG_P_Support", "Primary_CG_StrengthTotal", "NonCust_CaregiverID", "NonCust_CaregiverRelation", "NC_CG_Needs", "NC_CG_Support", "NC_CG_StrengthTotal", "Surr_CaregiverID", "Surr_CaregiverRelation", "Surr_CG_Needs", "Surr_CG_Support", "Surr_CG_StrengthTotal")

  fas.long[fas.long[, score.vars] %>% is.na %>% rowSums == length(score.vars), other.vars] <- NA

  fas.wide <- fas.long %>%
    unite(col = scaletime, c(scale, time), sep = "_") %>%
    gather(key = var, value = value, adminDesc:youthOtherLivArrange) %>%
    unite(col = key, c(scaletime, var), sep = "_") %>%
    spread(key = key, value = value, fill = NA)

  fas <- fas.wide[, names(fas)]
  rm(fas.long, fas.wide, other.vars)

  # only interested in cases with assessments within the year of interest for report
  # year of interest for report: 10/1/2013 to 9/30/2016

  start.date <- as.Date("2009-10-1", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
  end.date <- as.Date("2016-9-30", format = "%Y-%m-%d")

  # convert date variables to date type
  fas[, grep(pattern = "Date", x = names(fas))] <- lapply(X = fas[, grep(pattern = "Date", x = names(fas))], FUN = as.Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

  #
  # for cases with revised initial assessments, replace initial data with revised initial data
  #

  # create variables that indicate whether a revised assessment is present or absent
  # some cases have multiple initial assessments, so check all of them for revisions
  # variable "max.e" reflects the maximum number of initial assessments present in the data sets

  seq.e <- grep(pattern = "E[1-9]+TInitial_assessDate", x = names(fas), value = TRUE) %>% regmatches(., gregexpr("[0-9]+", .)) %>% unlist
  max.e <- seq.e %>% max %>% as.numeric

  fas[, sapply(X = seq.e, FUN = function(x) paste0("e", x, "tr.initial"))] <- FALSE

  # function to replace initial assessment data with revised data

  for(num in seq.e){
    datecol <- paste0(upper, "_E", num, "TRInitial_assessDate")
    logcol <- paste0("e", num, "tr.initial")
    if(length(grep(pattern = paste0("E", num, "TRInitial"), names(fas))) > 0) fas[(fas[ , datecol] >= start.date) & (fas[, datecol] <= end.date) & (!is.na(fas[ , datecol])), logcol] <- TRUE
    fas[fas[, logcol] == TRUE, grep(pattern = paste0("E", num, "TInitial"), x = names(fas))] <- fas[fas[, logcol] == TRUE, grep(pattern = paste0("E", num, "TRInitial"), x = names(fas))]
  }
  rm(num, datecol, logcol)

  # delete revised assessment data columns because they are redundant
  # prevents them from being considered as a recent assessment
  if(length(grep(pattern = paste0("E[1-", max.e, "]TRInitial"), names(fas))) > 0)
    fas <- fas[, -grep(pattern = paste0("E[1-", max.e, "]TRInitial"), names(fas))]

  #
  # create variables to indicate the presence or absence of an initial assessment
  #

  fas[, sapply(X = seq.e, FUN = function(x) paste0("e", x, "t.initial"))] <- FALSE

  for(num in seq.e){
    datecol <- paste0(upper, "_E", num, "TInitial_assessDate")
    fas[fas[, datecol] >= start.date & fas[, datecol] <= end.date & !is.na(fas[, datecol]), paste0("e", num, "t.initial")] <- TRUE
    fas[rowSums(is.na(fas[paste0(upper, "_E", num, "TInitial_", score.vars)])) == length(score.vars), paste0("e", num, "t.initial")] <- FALSE # do not consider an assessment as present if all the scores are missing
  }

  rm(num, datecol)

  # some cases have multiple initial assessments within the year of interest
  # use the earliest one
  # create a variable that indicates which initial assessment is used

  fas$et.initial <- 0

  for(num in rev(seq.e)){
    fas$et.initial[fas[, paste0("e", num, "t.initial")] == TRUE] <- as.numeric(num)
  }
  rm(num)

  #
  # create a set of initial assessment variables that applies to all children
  #

  # delete cases without an initial assessment
  fas <- fas[fas$et.initial != 0, ]

  init.cols <- fas %>% select(matches(paste0(upper, "_E1TInitial")))

  init.colnames <- grep(pattern = paste0(upper, "_E1TInitial"), x = names(fas), value = TRUE)
  init.colnames <- paste0(upper, "_", gsub(pattern = paste0(upper, "_E1T"), replacement = "", x = init.colnames))
  names(init.cols) <- init.colnames

  fas <- cbind(fas, init.cols)
  rm(init.cols, init.colnames)

  for(num in seq.e[2:length(seq.e)]){
    fas[fas$et.initial == as.numeric(num), grep(pattern = paste0(upper, "_Initial"), x = names(fas))] <- fas[fas$et.initial == as.numeric(num), grep(pattern = paste0(upper, "_E", num, "TInitial"), x = names(fas))]
  }

  #
  # create a set of most recent assessment variables that applies to all children
  #

  # create variables that indicate number of days that have passed since the initial assessment for each assessment period

  days <- lapply(X = fas[, grep(pattern = "assessDate", names(fas))], FUN = function(x) x - fas[, paste0(upper, "_Initial_assessDate")]) %>% unlist %>% matrix(nrow = nrow(fas), byrow = FALSE) %>% data.frame

  names(days) <- grep(pattern = "assessDate", x = names(fas), value = TRUE) %>% sub(pattern = paste0(upper, "_"), replacement = "", x = .) %>% sub(pattern = "_assessDate", replacement = "", x = .) %>% paste(., "_days_pass", sep = "")

  fas <- cbind(fas, days)
  rm(days)

  fas$Initial_days_pass <- NULL

  # replace 0 or negative days passed with NA
  fas[, grep(pattern = "days_pass", x = names(fas))][fas[, grep(pattern = "days_pass", names(fas))] <= 0] <- NA

  # the code following the chunk below creates variables for the most recent assessment data
  # it is easier to execute the code if cases with only an initial assessment are not in the data set
  # add these cases back to the data set later

  # some data sets do not have any cases with a most recent assessment
  if((rowSums(is.na(fas[grep(pattern = "days_pass", names(fas), value = TRUE)])) == ncol(fas[grep(pattern = "days_pass", names(fas), value = TRUE)])) %>% sum != nrow(fas)) {

    init.only <- fas[which(rowSums(is.na(fas[grep(pattern = "days_pass", names(fas), value = TRUE)])) == ncol(fas[grep(pattern = "days_pass", names(fas), value = TRUE)])), ]
    fas <- fas[-which(rowSums(is.na(fas[grep(pattern = "days_pass", names(fas), value = TRUE)])) == ncol(fas[grep(pattern = "days_pass", names(fas), value = TRUE)])), ]

    # calculate the max days between the initial and most recent assessments
    fas$rec_days <- apply(X = fas[grep(pattern = "days_pass", x = names(fas), value = TRUE)], MARGIN = 1, FUN = max, na.rm = TRUE)

    # create a variable that indicates the time period of the most recent assessment

    days.pass.cols <- fas[grep(pattern = "days_pass", x = names(fas), value = TRUE)]

    fas$rec_time <- colnames(days.pass.cols)[apply(X = days.pass.cols, MARGIN = 1, FUN = which.max)] %>% sub(pattern = "_days_pass", replacement = "", x = .)

    rm(days.pass.cols)

    # create most recent assessment variables

    rec.cols <- apply(X = fas, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) x[grep(pattern = paste0(upper, "_Recent_"), names(x))] <- x[grep(pattern = paste(paste0(upper, "_"), x["rec_time"], sep = ""), names(x))]) %>% t %>% data.frame

    rec.colnames <- grep(pattern = paste0(upper, "_Initial"), x = names(fas), value = TRUE) %>% gsub(pattern = "Initial", replacement = "Recent", x = .)
    names(rec.cols) <- rec.colnames

    fas <- cbind(fas, rec.cols)
    rm(rec.cols)
  }

  #
  # limit data set to background variables, initial, and most recent assessments
  # add cases only with initial assessment back to data set
  #

  fas <- fas[, c(1:which(colnames(fas) == "E1_endDate"), which(colnames(fas) == "e1tr.initial"):ncol(fas))]

  # some data sets do not have any cases with a most recent assessment
  if((rowSums(is.na(fas[grep(pattern = "days_pass", names(fas), value = TRUE)])) == ncol(fas[grep(pattern = "days_pass", names(fas), value = TRUE)])) %>% sum != nrow(fas)) {

    init.only <- init.only[, c(1:which(colnames(init.only) == "E1_endDate"), which(colnames(init.only) == "e1tr.initial"):ncol(init.only))]

    fas <- bind_rows(fas, init.only)
    rm(init.only)
  }

  # add filename to data sets
  fas$filename <- file

  write.csv(fas, paste0("data/", lower, "/bref/", gsub(pattern = "\\.", replacement = "_bref.", file)), row.names = FALSE)

}



# delete assessment data that are not from the initial or last assessments from all cafas data sets

cafas.files <- list.files("data/cafas/items-del", pattern = ".csv")

for (file in cafas.files){
  del.mid(file)
}

# delete assessment data that are not from the initial or last assessments from all pecfas data sets

pecfas.files <- list.files("data/pecfas/items-del", pattern = ".csv")

for (file in pecfas.files){
  del.mid(file)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a cutdown version of the dataframe just before the error is thrown? The error is being produced because of 3 or so lines, so everythign before this point is fairly unimportant. The actions though are important and you should provide a dataframe that reflects what the modifications are.

Comment: Hello Amar, thanks for replying so quickly! If I understand you correctly, you're asking for a copy of the dataset with all of the modifications up until the point where the script fails. This link should take you to that version of the dataset. https://www.dropbox.com/s/vl1q4q73l6p6ss2/pecfas_100203%20%5Bmi-%20southwest%20counseling%20solutions%5D_bref.csv?dl=0

Comment: Here is another version of the dataset from slightly earlier, since the one I posted above contained only the column names. https://www.dropbox.com/s/vl1q4q73l6p6ss2/pecfas_100203%20%5Bmi-%20southwest%20counseling%20solutions%5D_bref.csv?dl=0

Comment: I would suggest to get rid of the function `del.mid` for now. Try to run your code line by line for the file in question only. When you reach the line that produce error, post the input data & that line here. It would be easier for others to help. As of now, your whole code is fairly long and I don't thin that many people will have time to debug it for you

Comment: Hi Tung, I typically run it section by section. The rest of the code works fine, it's specifically the section with rec.cols and rec.colnames.